# second transition won't work

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I started going through `d3.js` a day ago. I have a small snippet of code that runs when a svg rectangle element is clicked on. In this code snippet the only second transition works not the first one.

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var colors = ["blue", "darkblue", "black", "red", "green"]

var svg = body.append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 400)

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);

rect.on("click", function () {
    rect.transition()
        .style("fill", colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) / 2)])
        .attr("x", 400)
        .ease("elastic")
        .duration(1500);

    rect.transition()
        .style("fill", colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) / 2)])
        .attr("y", 300)
        .ease("elastic")
        .duration(1500);
});
```

Why is it not running first `transition`? Here is the [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdhama/VgP9D/6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting up transitions in two separate bits of code, you're overwriting the first with the second before it had a chance to run. To add another transition after one has finished, simply do a `.transition()` again in the same block of code:

```
rect.transition()
    .style("fill", colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) / 2)])
    .attr("x", 400)
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(1500)
    .transition()
    .style("fill", colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) / 2)])
    .attr("y", 300)
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(1500);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VgP9D/7/).